# Call Javascript function in an extended form

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to implement this datepicker function/gadget in 2 places of a form.

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

The first place works perfectly fine but, the second place, which is within a cloned form created by an extend form function, does not load at all.

I tried placing the script in different places but it seems irrelevant. Do we need a specific way to call a js function within a cloned form?

The first place (2 datepickers):

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[Condition][0][start]"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">      
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="click" name="data[Condition][0][end]"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second place (another 2), with the 2 js functions at the end that clone the form and call datepicker respectively:

```
<span id="readroot2" style="display: none">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">      
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="click" name="end"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</span>
<span id="writeroot2"></span>       
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onClick="moreFields2()" value="Give me more fields!" />
<script>
    //Clone function
    var newcounter = 0;
    function moreFields2() {
        newcounter++;
        var newField = document.getElementById('readroot2').cloneNode(true);
        newField.id = '';
        newField.style.display = 'block';
        var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for]');
            for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
                var theNames = newFields[i].name
                if (theNames)
                    newFields[i].name = "data[Condition][" + newcounter + "][" + theNames + "]";
                var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
                if (theNames2)
                    newFields[i].id = theNames2 + newcounter;
                var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
                if (theNames3)
                    newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + newcounter;      
            }           
        var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot2');
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere);
    }

    //Call datepicker
    $(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to initialise the datepicker for the newly created elements *after* you've cloned your form. jQuery selectors, plug-in initialisation, event handler bindings, etc. aren't retroactively applied.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to JS. If it's not too much a trouble would you mind advising how to initialise the call after the form's cloned?

Comment: Create a function that contains the `$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(...);` bit of code, then call that in two places: the DOM ready handler (i.e. where you currently have that bit of code) and then at the end of your moreFields2() function.

Comment: Thanks so much Anthony. Did it :)

Comment: Why are we answering in comments now?

Comment: Oh and what about functions? Can I just wrap in that moreFields2() function just like the call?